# A way to detect CATiledLayer?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, catiledlayer

I am using CATiledLayer to display a pdf page..
But the layer do have some time to draw context.

Therefore, I try to add an background beside this layer and remove the background after CATiledLayer is successful display..

My question is **Is there any ways to detect the drawing status of CATiledLayer?**

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

subclass your CATiledLayer and make fadeDuration of tiledlayer to 0.0

Answer (score 0):

A "hacky" way of doing is to pre-calculate how much tiles will be rendered, and then count the calls to `- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer*)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context`. It's a pretty insecure though and most likely only works on the initial zoom level. CATiledLayer caches its tiles and doesn't tell you what is cached and what will be redrawn.